# how to get rid of these weird black mesh patches on my donut icing?

Tags: animation

so, i am following a youtube tutorial of how to make the donut and i followed the exact same steps.. i repeated the whole process 3 times to make sure i am not doing any mistake but still these black mesh patches do not go away. i am a beginner and this is the first time i am using blender. please help me.These appear only while moving or rotating the donut And also i already solidified the icing but it does not go(but it reduced little but still there). i will attach the image:
[image]

Comment: you probably have 2 donut objects overlapping

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your icing is overlapping the donut. Select it and move it up a little bit and it should disappear.

Comment: Yes, I think the icing is overlapping with the donut or maybe there is a duplicate object overlapping the main one.